# pandas - how to use boolean Series to delete DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program which does this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5),
                 columns=['a','b','c','d','e',])
```

From there, I'm trying to delete columns whose mean is > 0

If I make

```
s = df1.mean() > 0
```

Then s, in my case, is a pandas series equal to:

```
a    False
b    False
c     True
d     True
e    False
dtype: bool
```

But how can I apply that to df1 so that cols c and d are deleted?

Am I approaching the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1[df1.columns[~s]]
```

This will eliminate all columns where `s` is True, namely `c` and `d`.

Another way to achieve this would be:

```
df1.loc[:, ~s]
```